# NSView mouse tracking

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm facing a strange behavior with Cocoa NSView on Mac OS X.

I've a custom NSView in a NSView container, this custom NSView tracks mouse movements, clicks, and has a tooltip.
When I add a NSView above the described view, I can still see the tooltips even if the view with the tooltip is under, behind and not visible.

I'm pretty sure that I misunderstood something in the event handling chain. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is that you are not supposed to have overlapping views in Cocoa. Or at least, the behavior then becomes undefined. A view can be a subview of another view, but not simply a sibling within the bounds of the other view.

However, one way to solve your particular problem is to make the view underneath hidden, using the `setHidden:` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using it anymore you can call the removeFromSuperview method.

```
NSView *myView
[myView alloc] init]
// do stuff
[myView removeFromSuperview]
```

if you just don't want it to receive events you can call the resignFirstResponder method

```
NSView *myView
[[myView alloc] init] 
// do stuff
[myView resignFirstResponder]
```