# Tooltips showing from underneath an NSView/NSBox

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview, xcode-storyboard

I'm running into an issue in a mac osx app. I'm displaying a popover using an NSBox and I'm noticing tooltips from elements underneath are showing through

[image]

I've created a quick demo project to show the issue: https://github.com/GP89/tooltipper

I've tried everything I can think of

- setting `nextResponder` on the box to nil
- overriding all the mouse event handlers I can find in a subclass of NSBox (eg. `mouseMoved`)
- setting `acceptsTouchEvents` to false

Plus a bunch of searching online

I did find some similar issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590763/mouse-events-bleeding-through-nsview) where they silence mouse events, but I can't seem to find a way of doing it for tooltips

Comment: See [NSView mouse tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225573/nsview-mouse-tracking?rq=1). Solution: use a real popover with `NSPopover`.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks, as far as I know it wont be possible to have a similar appearance to what I have above with `NSPopover`